# Rx - Multiple consumers without losing messages

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I want multiple consumers and each of them should get all the messages (without missing any of them).

The actual is idea is that I have a firehose of stuff coming through a redis pub/sub and I need to distribute it to a number of websocket connections, so basically whenever a message comes from redis, it needs to be distributed through all websockets connections.

How do I achieve that with `System.Reactive`? Will the following work?

```cs
var obs1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).Select(x =>
{
    var publishVal = x;
    Console.WriteLine($@"observer1 publishing {publishVal}");
    return publishVal;
}).Publish();

var sub1 = obs1.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($@"subscriber1 value {x}"));
var sub2 = obs1.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($@"subscriber2 value {x}"));

obs1.Connect();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've described, this will work:

```
var obs1 =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($@"observer1 publishing {x}"));

var sub1 = obs1.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($@"subscriber1 value {x}"));
var sub2 = obs1.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($@"subscriber2 value {x}"));
```

Comment: This will create two subscriptions to the `obs1` though. My understanding is that the OP wants to subscribe to the producer only once.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - They did not specifically say that. I could imagine that it's what they want, but I'm not entirely sure. The question is unclear.