Channel output becomes slow with multiple readers
I'm testing System.Threading.Channels and trying to create a "Publisher-Subscriber" or "Single Producer, Multiple Consumers" kind of scenario.
When I have more than one reader for a channel the output becomes slow. I'm using WPF to test this case. As you can see in the attached video, when more than one Window (Subscriber/Reader) opens, for some reason the output starts slowing down. I've already set SingleReader = false in Channel's options. What's wrong here?
Here is the repo if you want to try it out.
Thanks.
public static class DataChannel
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Subscription<int>> Subscriptions = new();
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task> Writers = new();

    public static ChannelReader<int> Subscribe(string key)
    {
        var subscription = Subscriptions.GetOrAdd(key, k => new Subscription<int>
        {
            Key = k,
            DataChannel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<int>(new UnboundedChannelOptions
            {
                SingleReader = false,
                SingleWriter = true
            })
        });

        Writers.GetOrAdd(key, _ => StartWriterTask(subscription.DataChannel.Writer));

        return subscription.DataChannel.Reader;
    }

    private static Task StartWriterTask(ChannelWriter<int> writer)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                await writer.WriteAsync(++i);
                await Task.Delay(500);
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
}

public partial class Subscription<T> : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty] private Channel<T> _dataChannel = null!;
    [ObservableProperty] private string _key = null!;
}


public partial class ConsumerWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty] private int _dataValue;

    public ConsumerWindowViewModel()
    {
        _ = SubscribeForData();
    }


    private Task SubscribeForData()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var reader = DataChannel.Subscribe("IntData");
            await foreach (var data in reader.ReadAllAsync())
            {
                DataValue = data;
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}



It isn't "slow", you are just seeing one of the worker threads randomly being able to grab a channel item.  The other thread won't see it.  So the views will never be in sync and one of them can easily be behind by 0.5 or 1.0 seconds or more.

How can it randomly grab an item? I mean the channel writer is same, writing value at the same time and readers waiting to read. So, as soon a value arrives both readers from different threads should be able to read the "Same" value at the "Same time". This is my understanding.

As a side note, the Task.Factory.StartNew doesn't understand async delegates. Use Task.Run instead. See this article for details.

@TheodorZoulias In this case it's fine since I'm not awaiting for any result from Task.Factory. Also, I do usually use Task.Run i replaced it with Factory just to see if that resolves my issue..

Why is a close vote happening on this question? Those running close vote, can please explain to me what's wrong with this question? Thanks.

I got my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72479688/multiple-consumers-without-losing-messages
